# "df = pd.read_csv('xxx.csv')" resets the date format in my csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, date

In my csv file, I save my dates in this format: "yyyy-mm-dd".
Every time I pull the data from csv and into a pandas dataframe, it will reset the format to "yyyy/mm/dd" in my csv file. This will cause errors if I test my code again, so I have to open the csv and reformat the date column to yyyy-mm-dd again.

Do you know why CSV does this? Is there a permanent solution to make sure my date format doesn't reset every time pandas reads my csv file?

Here is some of my code directly related to reading my csv file:

```
origindf = pd.read_csv('testlist.csv')
origindf = pd.DataFrame(origindf, columns=["ticker","date"])
origintickers = origindf['ticker'].values.tolist()
origintickersiterate = origindf['ticker'].values.tolist()
origindates = origindf['date'].values.tolist()

masterdf = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['ticker', 'date', 'time', 'vol', 'vwap', 'open', 'high', 'low','close','trades'])

for ticker in origintickersiterate:
    polygonapi = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    limit = 10000
    multiplier = 1
    timespan = 'minute'
    adjusted = 'False'
    theticker = origintickers.pop()
    thedate = origindates.pop()
```

Comment: CSV doesn't do that., and nothing will change the file if you are just reading it.  Do you have pandas write the data back out to the file?  How do you do that?  Show us some of your code.

Comment: The code I added is all the code directly related to the DataFrame that read_csv imports in

Comment: Nothing here will change the CSV file.

Comment: I should note: When I save my dataframe to a csv, it will save with the same "yyyy/mm/dd" format. I wonder if this is just a default setting in csv/excel?

Comment: If you are viewing the file in Excel, it may format it differently for display and save it differently.  Best to check the format in a text editor before reading the file with Excel

Comment: Don't confuse CSV with Excel. They're not the same. Excel just so happens to be able to open CSV files, but in general is not great for working with them.

Comment: Have you looked at the file in Notepad?  I'll bet the format is exactly what it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that pandas recognises the original text as dates, it will represent it as `datetime64[ns]` which is not text and how it displays on screen, eg with `df.head()` is irrelevant.  You can check the data formats with `df.dtypes` to make sure.

Pandas `to_csv` allows you to control the format of the output dates with the `date_format` parameter, eg:

```
df.to_csv('testlist.csv', date_format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

I suggest viewing the output in a text editor because Excel will parse the dates and may convert them.

Current documentation:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Comment: I do not change the csv. I only read it to grab data for the DataFrame

Comment: If you don't write the csv back to file, it cannot change, so I'm assuming either that Excel is changing it or Python is changing it.  Maybe it is something else.  Can you set it as read only?